# uitableview reloaddata cache?

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm having some problems with an UITableView and the method reloadData.

I'm refreshing the tableView when clicking over a refresh button with the last info in a data base ordered descendingly so the most recent items should appear in first position.

Every cell in my tableview is being filled with custom labels and uiimageviews.

Well... the thing is that when I press that refresh button and new data is found, the first 5 rows (which are the ones that are being shown in the display) aren't updated but the following rows do. However, if I press over any of the 5 first rows, they call correctly to the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method with the new data.

So, the problem is that the tableview's "visual" content of the first 5 rows is not being updated.

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks!

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d:%d", [ indexPath indexAtPosition: 0 ], [ indexPath indexAtPosition:1 ]];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        Activity *activity = [[self.activities valueForKey:[[[self.activities allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text=@"";
        //Mostramos el nombre
        UILabel *label= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, -5, 200, 34)];
        label.text = [activity name];
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell addSubview:label];
        [label release];

        //Mostramos la imagen
        UIImageView *leftImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 3, 50, 50)];
        [cell addSubview:leftImage];


        UITextView *textView=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 25, 200, 38)];
        textView.editable = NO;
        textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        textView.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-8,-8,0,0);
        textView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        [cell addSubview:textView];

        switch ([activity notType]) {
            case 0:
                textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"requestPUSH",@""),[activity name]];
                leftImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ios.png"];
                break;
            case 1:
                textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"MPCreatedPushString",@""),[activity name],[activity nameItem]];
                leftImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mpNew.png"];
                break;
            case 2:
                textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"MPUpdatedPushString",@""),[activity name],[activity nameItem]];
                leftImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mpUpdated.png"];
                break;
            case 3:
                textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"MPDeletedPushString",@""),[activity name],[activity nameItem]];
                leftImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ios.png"];
                break;
            case 4:
                textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"MPGuestConfirmationPUSHString",@""),[activity name],[activity nameItem]];
                leftImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"attend.png"];
                break;
            case 5:
                if ([[activity message] isEqualToString:@"noData"]) {
                    textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"ShoutPushString",@""),[activity name]];
                }else{
                    textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"ShoutPushStringWithData",@""),[activity name], [activity message]];
                }
                UIImage *contactImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[[activity person] pic]];
                if (contactImage!=nil) {
                    leftImage.image = contactImage;
                    //redondeamos bordes
                    CALayer * l = [leftImage layer];
                    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
                    [l setCornerRadius:5.0];
                }else{
                    leftImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ios.png"];
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"CheckinPushString",@""),[activity name],[activity nameItem]];
                leftImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ios.png"];
                break;
            case 7:
                textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"MPGuestRejectionPUSHString",@""),[activity name],[activity nameItem]];
                leftImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reject.png"];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        [leftImage release];
        [textView release];


        //Mostrar fecha
        double timestamp = [[activity datetime] doubleValue]/1000;
        NSString *dateShow;

        NSDate *datetime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
        dateShow=[dateFormat stringFromDate:datetime];

        UILabel *label2= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 0, 70, 20)];
        label2.text = dateShow;
        label2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label2.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [cell addSubview:label2];
        [label2 release];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post your cell creation code?

Comment: Code added, it's not few, hehe! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, so you give each cell a unique cell identifier. Do you have a reason for that?
Mostly people try to patch their misunderstanding of iOS table views that way ...

When you reload your table this call `UITableViewCell *cell = [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];`
 will get  you a cell to reuse (read already contains content).

But your code only works for "fresh" cells : `if (cell == nil) {`
, you're just not prepared for that case ...

Comment: Wow! Didn't know about that, I don't have to reuse the cells. That solved my problem!
Thank you very much!